# Extract Oracle Pivot table to CSV file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a created a pivot table in Oracle in order to extract data from a rather large and complex table to try and use the data to merge with some letters

Ideally what I need to do is to then export the data to a CSV file for transfer to the hybrid mail solution we have here.

I am struggling with the syntax of how the export to the CSV file might work in this case since some of the columns are created as part of the pivot process.

I had also thought of creating a temporary table using the "create global temporary table as select * from - and then the query for the pivot table. However trying this and then trying to select from the table created by the pivot leads to another complication as I am unable to query the dynamically created column as it is surrounded by '' single quotes.

Any ideas / comments suggestions gratefully received

The query to create the PIVOT table looks like this

```
select *
from 
(
select
BAA_QSA_ID ,
BAA_ASM_ID ,
BAA_SUBJECT_ID ,
PER_FIRST_NAMES ||' '|| per_surname as per_name,
case 
  when BAA_QST_DESC = 'Name of Person or Organisation of contact and their contact details' then 'PER_ORG_OF_CONTACT' else BAA_QST_CODE end as BAA_QST_CODE,
case 
  when BAA_QST_TYPE = 'QUE' then BAA_QUE_VALUE 
  when BAA_QST_TYPE = 'RVA' then (select RVA_DESC from o_Ref_values where BAA_RVA_VALUE = RVA_CODE and RVA_DOMAIN = 'CONTACT_OUTCOME')
end as answer
from 
BO_ASSESSMENT_ANSWERS left join o_persons on BAA_SUBJECT_ID = PER_ID 
where
BAA_QSA_ID='A1457'
to_date(BAA_ASM_END_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') = to_Date(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')
and 
(BAA_QST_CODE = 'CONTACT_OUTCOME' or BAA_QST_DESC = 'Name of Person or Organisation of contact and their contact details')
order by 3
) 
PIVOT
(
MAX(ANSWER) 
for BAA_QST_CODE in ('CONTACT_OUTCOME','PER_ORG_OF_CONTACT')
)
```

The table that comes out of it looks quite normal except that the last two columns, the ones created from the pivot have the names surrounded by the single quotes as shown in the SQL that creates the columns

Comment: Can you post the query (or atleast a sample of it) you're trying to work with and explain the complication bit with an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think actually I may now be on track to solving this based on a post I saw just before I closed down last night.

The problem with being able to query the temporary table was based on the fact that I was incorrectly creating the columns in the pivot table

the Pivot should read
PIVOT
(
MAX(ANSWER) 
for BAA_QST_CODE in ('CONTACT_OUTCOME' as CONTACT_OUTCOME ,'PER_ORG_OF_CONTACT' as PER_ORG_OF_CONTACT )
)

The column names then become queryable and I presume / hope I should be able to extract from the temporary table into a CSV file

Comment: Don't forget that the new SQLcl tool has CSV output built in, along with other output formats.

Comment: Unfortunately the environment I am working in is not particularly advanced in that respect so I am going to have to do it 'old school' as part of a shell script as it is something we want to be able to run overnight

Comment: Got it.  Have you seen Tom's suggestion for CSVs: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:88212348059

Comment: Yes I saw that previously and whilst it looks like a solution the database is part of a proprietary application and adding additional procedures etc risks invalidating our support contract

Comment: I have managed to sort out the creation of the temporary table which pivots the data the way I want it to but actually extracting the data from that is proving a little problematic

Comment: The problem with extracting the file into a CSV file seems to stem from the size of the table that is created based on the pivot

Comment: Right I finally think I have nailed this and a lot of the problems stem from the nature of global temporary tables in Oracle, accessing them and the how they are disposed of. The long and short of it in my case is that is far and away easier to actually create a couple of temporary physical tables to hold the data ( i may revise this to one when I have some additional time to fiddle with this)  and then extract to CSV from there. the whole environment of shell script, SQL Plus , a complex pivot query and its results brought in a number of interesting things and I have learnt a lot!